# Is there any way to use native android player for videos?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm developing an android app and I wanted to do something like that:
I have simple button and when I press it, the android native player pops with video up

Comment: there is.  Look up "intent"s and how to send them to external apps.  You would need the uri to the file you want played and you would simply send that to the "default_media_player" (or something simliar) with an intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri data = Uri.parse(Path to video file);
intent.setDataAndType(data, "video/mp4");
startActivity(intent);
```

use this if you don't want to use videoview